# Did Humble Bundle stop supporting the "Activate on Steam" option?

Tags: steam, humble-bundle

There was a time where you could link your Steam account to your Humble Bundle account and have the codes automatically redeem as you clicked them, without all of the copy-paste-wait-wait more-click next-wait more-keep waiting-click finish business.  This was an excellent feature and I loved it.  But now it doesn't appear to work for me.

It still shows my account linked to a Steam account, so the framework hasn't been *removed*, but it doesn't seem to function for me. Is this working normally when it gives me the codes, or is it something in my own Humble Bundle or Steam account that's broken and I should try to fix?

(If it is something broken, troubleshooting help is also appreciated, but not necessary to answer my question.)

Comment: Sometime last year, Steam has decided to remove OAuth support. So this meant that keys can't be redeemed by link (or third-parties) on behalf of you anymore. They've talked about it [in this HumbleMumble blog post](http://blog.humblebundle.com/post/107906804069/changes-in-steam-key-redemption).

Comment: @schnaader Er.. I *was* the one who pointed out that HB stopped doing OAuth key redemption. (Last line of the question)

Comment: They just remove it

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Essentially, yes.**
According to this [Humble Mumble blog post](http://blog.humblebundle.com/post/107906804069/changes-in-steam-key-redemption), they have stated that they'll be removing OAuth support for Steam, which is the main method of redeeming keys through a third-party/link.

And that all purchases made before the 12<sup>th</sup> of January 2015 can still use this method up to around the start of Febuary. Anything bought after the 12<sup>th</sup> or is unredeemed by the start of Febuary will be converted into actual usable keys... Codes.

**So why?**
Nobody knows; Steam has not released an official announcement.. Not that I could find (or even remember seeing popping up in my Steam news feed) anyway, but it's open to speculation on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/2s6v9s/steam_removing_oauth_key_redemption/).

**Update:**
To remedy this, Steam has (around a year ago at the time of this edit) has permitted key redemption through the web browser [here](https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey).

You can pre-fill the key to add a query with the key `key` in the URL:

```
https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey?key=AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC  
https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey?key=AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE
https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey?key=237ABCDGHJLPRST%2023
https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey?key=This%20is%20definitely%20not%20a%20key
```

Comment: there were also some [threads on the steam forums](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/12/622954302099562973/) when this happened, but nothing official

Comment: Word on the street is that Steam deprecated the API being used to activate products.

Comment: @Powerlord that much is certain, the real question is _why_.

Comment: @Seiyria I could ask the one person I know at Valve, but I doubt he'd actually give me an answer (he tends to ignore **any** Valve-related questions I ask him).

Comment: @Powerlord One too many HL3 questions?

Comment: The blog post was updated to say "Steam is removing support for OAuth, so we'll be returning to the system we used before, which requires you to manually redeem your Steam keys".

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, yes Valve stopped Humble Bundle offering this functionality a long time ago. However, I've created an open-source Chrome plugin, [Steam Redeem](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/steam-redeem/cepidlbnnmiiaeginikgkedgmjambcha), that attempts to recreate this behaviour.

Basically once installed it detects Humble Bundle keys in your browser and injects a redeem button. When you press the button it uses the Steam browser API (accessible manually at https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey) to redeem your steam key. There's also built-in bulk redemption, if you click the Steam Redeem logo (next to your address bar) it will automatically redeem all keys visible on the page.

It's a work in progress, and being open source, contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up, for future querents, Valve began offering [web-based activation of keys](https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey#) again in August 2017, and Humble Bundle employs this by providing a button that brings up that page with the key filled in. If you are already logged into Steam, it's essentially a three-click process. Once on the Humble Site to Reedem on Steam, one to accept the Steam agreement, and then one to Redeem. This is, of course, substantially similar to the plugin that Benjamin apparently created. I don't know whether they employed his code, or just rolled their own, similar, solution.